# What are the status codes where the user should be redirected to a response page?

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, backend

I'm currently developing a global error handler that catches the HTTP server error status codes and I'm planning to do a different action depending on the code that client receives but I don't know if I should show the user a response page of something different from a 500 or 404.

What would you do?

**Edit:** I have different response pages: bad-request, forbidden, internal-server-error, method-not-allowed, service-unavailable, unauthorized and not-found.
I'm aware that I should redirect the user to a response page if the status code is 404 (not-found) or 500 (internal-server-error) but I'm not really sure if I should redirect the user if one of the others that I mentioned above occur. I do know that if the response is an unauthorized maybe I should redirect him to a login page.

So my question is: what are the response status that apply to a user redirection?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 302 is the signal gor redirect

Answer (score 0):

Your respond should be user friendliness where they identify actual problem. Your client can be either technical or non-technical. So you can customize the error. Based on the error, you decide yourself that you need to redirect or show a pop-up or etc.

For example, your are using `username` which is `unique`. Accidentally someone tries to register it, that time you have show the error of user existence in the page, not to redirect. As well, you get 500 Internal server error, that time you may decide to redirect a page or show the page itself.

Comment: Hi.

Thanks for answering. I've edited my answer to explain myself a little more.